# Arrays ,pointers and string manipulation

Tags: c, function

I want make a game where my database contains 20 specific words. The program chooses a word randomly and the user can make 5 mistakes or successfully guess the word.

1. If the word is `"literature"` (10 letters), it prints 10 asterisks (`*`) then asks for a letter.
2. If the letter is right, the program finds its place and prints like `***e*****e` until the user gets all letter right or fails 5 times.
3. The code below gives a compiler error in func *memcpy line invalid conversion const void to void and char to const void*.

Can you check if anything is wrong or missing? If there is any mistake, where is it?

Code:

```
    int func(int);

    int main()
    {

    int ErrorCount=5;

    while(ErrorCount!=0){
                    ErrorCount=func(ErrorCount);
                   }   

        if(ErrorCount==0)
                {
                printf("GAME OVER\n");          
                }

      getch();

      return 0; 
    }


    int func(int ErrorCount)
    {
     //const char *str[19];
     const char *str[20] = {
     "literature","scholar", "enormous", "influence", "orchestra",
     "publication", "teacher", "member", "final", "phonograph",
     "striking", "different", "screwdriver", "intelligient",
     "executed", "oldest", "people", "requiring", "pioneer",
     "telephone"
      };


    char temp[1000];
    char c[2];
    int k,x=0;
    int i;
    i=rand()%19;

    for(k=0;k!=strlen(str[i]);k++)
       {
       scanf("*",&temp[k]);
       printf("%s\n",temp);
       }
    printf("Write a Letter\n");
    scanf("%c",c);

    for(x=0;x!=strlen(str[i]);x++)
    {
         if(str[x]==c){                          
             memcpy(str[x],temp[x]);          
             printf("%s",temp);                                       
                       }                    
         else{ 
              printf("Wrong\n");
              ErrorCount--;
              }                                       

              }

     return ErrorCount;       
    }
```

Comment: temp[x] is not a string(pointer to char) but a char.

Comment: I fixed like char temp; but now it gives error invalid char[int] in scanf line scanf("*",&temp[k]);

Comment: You cant compare strings like `str[x]==c`. Use strcmp().

Comment: You should be using `if (scanf("%c", &c) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "Read failed\n"); exit(1); }` or something similar. The `&c` is crucial; it is fatally flawed without the ampersand. The test is better because it ensures the program stops on reaching EOF. Your indentation is erratic; choose a [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) layout and stick to it. `memcpy()` takes three arguments, not two; the first two should be pointers. Your inner loop reports that 'e' is wrong when scanning 'literature'; you have to scan the whole string and report if the letter is not found anywhere.

Comment: There's so many errors... just **don't** write a line of code unless you understand what it does. And if you don't, then read up on it. You can't just take a guess when programming.

Comment: I fixed comp string if(strcmp(str[x],c)==0) but it still gives error in scanf line 2.nd comment above!

Comment: Urgh; I have to take back my `scanf("%c", &c)` comment; you declared `char c[2];` which means your call to `scanf()` is correct, but you need to use `c[0]` or `*c` to refer to the character that the user entered. You shouldn't need to use `memcpy()` at all; you might use `memset(temp, '*', strlen(str[i])); temp[strlen(str[i])] = '\0';` to set the string to all asterisks.  It would be a good idea to have `int len = strlen(str[i]);` and use `len` in place of `strlen(str[i])`.

Comment: The loop `for(k=0;k!=strlen(str[i]);k++) { scanf("*",&temp[k]); printf("%s\n",temp); }` is bogus; you should not be using `scanf()` at all; and you should not be printing the string each time, especially as it is not guaranteed to be null terminated.  Either us `memset()` or the loop should be assigning `*` to each element `temp[k]`, and then you need to null terminate the string, and only when all that's done do you print it, once.

Comment: should i give you a little simple code by modifying your code?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   Thank for all the comment i am gonna try to fix the code like what you said.I am confused like hell.

Comment: @BhaveshMunot If you can it would be like christmas for me thank you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler tried to use memset but it need void type in memset line compiler gives invalid conversion char to void should i make char  temp to void temp then it gives error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't submit this code, but you can learn from it:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int hangman(int maxErrors);

int main(void)
{
    enum { MAX_ERROR_COUNT = 5 };
    int ErrorCount = MAX_ERROR_COUNT;

    srand(time(0));

    while (ErrorCount != 0)
        ErrorCount = hangman(MAX_ERROR_COUNT);

    printf("GAME OVER\n");
    return 0;
}

int hangman(int ErrorCount)
{
    const char *str[] =
    {
        "literature", "scholar", "enormous", "influence", "orchestra",
        "publication", "teacher", "member", "final", "phonograph",
        "striking", "different", "screwdriver", "intelligent",
        "executed", "oldest", "people", "requiring", "pioneer",
        "telephone", "syzygy",
    };
    enum { NUM_WORDS = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]) };

    char temp[100];
    char c;
    int x = 0;
    int i = rand() % NUM_WORDS;
    const char *word = str[i];
    int len = strlen(word);
    int unguessed = len;

    memset(temp, '*', len);
    temp[len] = '\0';

    while (ErrorCount > 0 && unguessed > 0)
    {
        int matches = 0;
        printf("Word: %s\n", temp);
        printf("Write a Letter\n");
        if (scanf(" %c", &c) != 1)
        {
            printf("Bye!\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        for (x = 0; x < len; x++)
        {
            if (word[x] == c)
            {
                temp[x] = c;
                unguessed--;
                matches++;
            }
        }

        if (matches == 0)
        {
            printf("%c did not match any letters of the word\n", c);
            ErrorCount--;
        }
    }

    if (unguessed == 0)
        printf("Congratulations!\n");
    else
        printf("Oops!\n");

    return ErrorCount;
}
```

Sample runs:

```
Word: ******
Write a Letter
e
Word: *e***e
Write a Letter
f
f did not match any letters of the word
Word: *e***e
Write a Letter
g
g did not match any letters of the word
Word: *e***e
Write a Letter
h
h did not match any letters of the word
Word: *e***e
Write a Letter
i
i did not match any letters of the word
Word: *e***e
Write a Letter
j
j did not match any letters of the word
Oops! The word was 'people'.
GAME OVER
```

and:

```
Word: **********
Write a Letter
e
e did not match any letters of the word
Word: **********
Write a Letter
o
Word: **o*o*****
Write a Letter
p
Word: p*o*o***p*
Write a Letter
h
Word: pho*o***ph
Write a Letter
n
Word: phono***ph
Write a Letter
g
Word: phonog**ph
Write a Letter
r
Word: phonogr*ph
Write a Letter
a
Congratulations! The word was 'phonograph'.
Word: ******
Write a Letter
Bye!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    char *chr, *c;
    char a;
    int error = 0, found = 0, i = 0;

    char *str[20] =
    {
    "literature","scholar", "enormous", "influence", "orchestra",
    "publication", "teacher", "member", "final", "phonograph",
    "striking", "different", "screwdriver", "intelligient",
    "executed", "oldest", "people", "requiring", "pioneer",
    "telephone"
    };

    i=rand()%19;

    chr = str[i];

    c = calloc(strlen(chr) + 1, 1);

    memset(c, '*', strlen(chr));

    while( 1 ){
        printf("Write a Letter ");

        scanf(" %c", &a);


        if(isalpha(a)){
            i = 0;
            found = 0;
            while(chr[i] != '\0'){
                if(chr[i] == a){c[i] = chr[i]; found = 1;}
                i++;
            }

            if(!found){error++;}

            if(error == 5){printf("You lose \n"); break;}
            if(!strcmp(chr, c)){printf("%s \n", c); break;}

            printf("%s \n", c);
        }
        else{printf("No letter. Try again \n");}
    }

    free(c);

    return 0;
}
```

valter

Comment: You need to null terminate the string after the `memset()`.  It shoudl really be `i = rand() % 20;` or, better, `enum { NUM_WORDS = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]) };` and `i = rand() % NUM_WORDS;`.  Then you can add words to the list without changing the rest of the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The **+1** in calloc is the null terminating character

Comment: Oh - sorry; yes.  I so seldom use `calloc()` that I didn't look for it, mainly because your code means that the space is written twice, once with nulls and one with asterisks.  Sure, it works...my bad.

Answer (score -1):

Have it :)
Here is Solution for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func(int, char [], char []);

int main() 
{

char *str[20] =
{
    "literature","scholar", "enormous", "influence", "orchestra",
    "publication", "teacher", "member", "final", "phonograph",
    "striking", "different", "screwdriver", "intelligient",
    "executed", "oldest", "people", "requiring", "pioneer",
    "telephone"
};

int ErrorCount=5;
char temp[50];
int k,x=0;
int i;


i=rand()%19;
for(k=0;k!=strlen(str[i]);k++)
{
    temp[k]='*';
}
temp[k]=0;
printf("\n%s\n", temp);

while(ErrorCount!=0)
{
    ErrorCount=func(ErrorCount, temp, str[i]);
}

if(ErrorCount==0)
{
        printf("GAME OVER\n");
}

return 0;
}


int func(int ErrorCount, char temp[], char word[])
{
char c;
int k,x=0;
int flag;

printf("\nWrite a Letter: ");
scanf("\n%c",&c);

flag=0;
for(x=0;x!=strlen(word);x++)
{
    //printf("word[%d]= %c %c", x, word[x], c);
     if(word[x]==c)
     {
         temp[x]=c;
         flag=1;
     }
}

if(flag)
    printf("\n%s\n", temp);
else
    printf("\nWrong\n");
flag=0;
for(x=0; x!=strlen(word); x++)
{
    if(temp[x]=='*')
    {
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag)
{
    if(ErrorCount==1)
        printf("You Lose\n");
    return --ErrorCount;
}
else
    printf("You Won\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: .. this is supposed to help the OP understand what was wrong, how exactly?

Comment: Where should i write my code which improved by comments?

Comment: thank you but it closing when 3 mistake happen and what is if(flag) do? i never saw if use like this!